# Replace specific part of a column when another column value above a threshold in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grepl

I have a dataframe such as;

```
COL1                           COL2
Canis_lupus1                   10
Cattus_cattus2                 10
Betta_splendes3                30
Rattus_domesticus_norvegicus3  20
Canis_lupus_OK                 90
Betta_splendes32               54
Canis_lupus_lupus              18
```

And I would like to replace in `COL1` each C**anis_lupus** content by : `homo_sapiens` when `COL2 is < 20`

Then I should get:

```
COL1                           COL2
Homos_sapiens1                   10
Cattus_cattus2                 10
Betta_splendes3                30
Rattus_domesticus_norvegicus3  20
Canis_lupus_OK                 90
Betta_splendes32               54
Homo_sapiens_lupus              18
```

Here is the df:

```
structure(list(COL1 = structure(c(5L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Betta_splendes3", 
"Betta_splendes32", "Canis_lupus_lupus", "Canis_lupus_OK", "Canis_lupus1", 
"Cattus_cattus2", "Rattus_domesticus_norvegicus3"), class = "factor"), 
    COL2 = c(10L, 10L, 30L, 20L, 90L, 54L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(COL1 = map2(COL1, COL2, ~ ifelse(str_detect(.x, "Canis_lupus") & .y < 20,
                                   str_replace(.x, "Canis_lupus", "homo_sapiens"), .x)))


                           COL1 COL2
1                 homo_sapiens1   10
2                Cattus_cattus2   10
3               Betta_splendes3   30
4 Rattus_domesticus_norvegicus3   20
5                Canis_lupus_OK   90
6              Betta_splendes32   54
7            homo_sapiens_lupus   18
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`, specify the condition in `i`, and use `sub` to replace the substring 'Canis_lupus' with 'Homo_sapiens' in 'COL1'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[COL2 < 20, COL1 := sub("Canis_lupus", "Homo_sapiens", COL1)]
```

-output

```
df
                            COL1 COL2
1:                 Homo_sapiens1   10
2:                Cattus_cattus2   10
3:               Betta_splendes3   30
4: Rattus_domesticus_norvegicus3   20
5:                Canis_lupus_OK   90
6:              Betta_splendes32   54
7:            Homo_sapiens_lupus   18
```